# Flutter - client side encryption of user data

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, cryptography

Are there any packages, frameworks, or services to do client-side encryption of user data in Flutter, using firebase as a server?

I hope to build an app that handles some of a user's personal financial information and so I want no one else, including me, to be able to access it. Firebase allows a Dev to see the unencrypted database so I need to do the encryption on the client-side.

I think this will probably have to involve a client-side symmetric key used for encrypting and decrypting the user data.

My worry is how to store this key.

(1) Randomly generated key stored locally - doesn't allow the user to switch between devices and is lost if the device is lost
(2) Store it in a Google Drive - requires the user to have a Google account. ([Advocated by this article](https://hackernoon.com/client-side-encryption-in-firebase-database-60dd55abadb2) from HackerMoon
(3) Generate it deterministically from a salted hash of the user's password (stored locally) - lost if the user forgets or changes their password.
(4) Allow the user to choose between a subset of the above

My question is similar to this one [How to encrypt user data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304258/how-to-encrypt-user-data-in-firebase) but it covers situations were data is transferred between users and hence uses public key cryptography.

Questions:
What is the best way to encrypt user-data for a firebase db?

And if it is to use a symmetric key, what is the best way to generate and store this key so the user doesn't risk losing access to their data?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/crypt, ask for a encryption password, so the data is never lost

Answer (score 1):

This one appeared to be the best solution for my case: flutter_secure_storage. It stores the data in an app specific container within the official key stores of iOS and Android